# Linear Independence of Vectors and Their Images After a Linear Mappings

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a linear mapping L: V -> W. How can I prove that if L(v1),...,L(vk) are linearly independent, then v1,...,vk are linearly independent? 
This is what I have so far:

```
There exists a1,...,ak where a1L(v1)+...+akL(vk) = 0, which implies:
L(a1v1+...akvk) = 0 and a1=...=ak=0
```

I don't know how to proceed from here. 
I also did `From above, we can see that a1v1+...+akvk = 0`. But later realized that this isn't necessarily correct.
Please help. Thanks!

Comment: You actually want to go in the opposite direction, i.e. prove the contrapositive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that if $v_1,\cdots, v_k$ are linearly dependent then $L(v_1),\cdots, L(v_k)$ are linearly dependent. If $v_1,\cdots, v_k$ are linearly dependent then there exists $a_1,\cdots, a_k,$ not all zero, such that $a_1v_1+\cdots +a_kv_k=0.$ Thus

$$0=L(0)=L(a_1v_1+\cdots +a_kv_k)=a_1L(v_1)+\cdots +a_kL(v_k),$$ which shows that $L(v_1),\cdots, L(v_k)$ are linearly dependent (because $a_1,\cdots, a_k,$ are not all zero).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the equation: $\alpha_1v_1+...+\alpha_nv_n=0$ claim that the only possible solution is $\alpha_n=0$ $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ and so $v_1,...,v_n$ are LI .

Proof: Apply ${L}$ on the equation and use the fact that it's linear to get;
$\alpha_1 L(v_1)+...+\alpha_nL(v_n)=0$ using the fact that $L(v_1),...,L(v_k)$ are linearly independent what can you conclude?